# How to call elementor repeater header from other control?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I show the titles of the custom post type in the select control option section. I am trying to get post custom title from id to title_field section.  Anyone can help me?

````
$options = array();


     $posts = get_posts( array(
         'post_type'  => 'portfolio'
     ) );
     
     foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
         $options[$post->ID] = get_the_title($post->ID);
     }

     $repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();

     $repeater->add_control(
         'posts',
         [
             'label' => __( 'Border Style', 'plugin-domain' ),
             'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
             'options' => $options,    
         ]
     );


     $this->add_control(
         'repeater_portfolio',
         [
             'label' => __('Repeater List', 'vaxholm'),
             'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
             'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
             'title_field' => get_the_title( '{{{ posts }}}' ),
         ]
     ); ```
````